# Strange Behavior with Console Logging on Internet Explorer 8+

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-8, session-cookies, windows-console

We are having a strange problem with Internet Explorer 8 and above.

Our Login process is handled using Javascript that posts hidden parameters being passed on to underlying servlet using AJAX call.

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('loaded');
    $j(".show-login").click( function() {
        var id=this.id.split("_",1);
        $j(".options-drop-down").hide();
        $j(".all-options-buttons").removeClass("xyz-options-button-selected");
        $j(".all-options-buttons").addClass("xyz-options-button");
        $j("#"+id+"_login_options").show();
        $j("#"+this.id).removeClass("xyz-options-button");
        $j("#"+this.id).addClass("xyz-options-button-selected");
    }); 
});
```

Every subsequent login throws us out due to invalid login, the variables are correctly received in the servlet, but somehow session values are incorrect.

Code works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Then I'd suggest revising it, as the _whole_ `console` object is not available in IE unless DevTools are opened - not only its `log` method.

Comment: Thanks for input, Summary updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of approaches with observing random JSESSION id being generated, We tried cleaning IE cookies, IE History, IE temp files but did nothing to resolve it.

We observed that whenever we had Internet Explorer Developer Tools (F12) opened, the script worked fine.

Finally we tried removing the following line from the javascript

```
console.log('loaded');
```

and the script started working fine.

So to Summarize:

**Calling any method on Console object interferes with normal Script execution when Internet Explorer Developer Tools is not running**